# how to select properties in the order from Object using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How to select properties in the order from List object using Linq?

```
public class Test
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
    public float D { get; set; }
}
```

for example `List<Test>` test1, so I want to the properties in the order of C,D,B,A from LINQ selection. How can we do that?

I am doing this for epplus excel package. which reads the in the list.

```
var dataRange = wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(
                    from s in list                    
                    select s, 
                    true,
                    OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add properties of `Test` class as columns to some other columns (`true`, `Medium2`) you need to make an anonymous type for it:

```
var dataRange = wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(
    from s in list
    select new {
        s.C
    ,   s.D
    ,   s.B
    ,   s.A
    ,   Flag=true
    ,   OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium2
    }
);
```